# How to create an _Arg, _Retval, _If operation in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to test all the operations available in tensorflow. For example, we can find 'Conv2d' in tf.nn module.
There are some operations started with an '_', e.g, '_Arg', '_ArrayToList', '_Retval'. I looked into the tensorflow source code, but still can't find how to create an operation '_Arg'. Please give me some instructions of how to find these operations, or what does these operations do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those operations are for an internal purpose, they are implemented in c++ so you'll need to download the source code, code (in c++) your own tests, compile and run them, since most of those operations do not have a Python wrapper.

Here you can find the [c++ api](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc).

This [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op) may help you if you are starting with tf operation. It does not do what you want, as it works with custom public operations.

You may have a look to the tests already implemented in tf code, fore example [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/abbeddb86f458c79910e1546fbb76694140c9362/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/function_test.cc) test file.

However, I will strongly recommend that you reconsider if you really need to test those functions. Testing every single function from TensorFlow, even the internal ones, is going to be a hard job.